# How to change file download destination on an android application

Tags: android, file, download

I'l developing an android application, the user will be able to download files on it, once a file is downloaded it is transferred automatically to the "downloads" folder on the phone. Is there a way to change the destination of the downloaded file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```java
Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(DOWNLOAD_FILE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
request.setDescription("Downloading a file");
long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
    .setTitle("File Downloading...")
    .setDescription("File Download Description")
    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "test.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the destination of the download request with the function:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationUri(android.net.Uri)

> Set the local destination for the downloaded file. Must be a file URI
>   to a path on external storage, and the calling application must have
>   the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
>
> The downloaded file is not scanned by MediaScanner. But it can be made
>   scannable by calling allowScanningByMediaScanner().
>
> By default, downloads are saved to a generated filename in the shared
>   download cache and may be deleted by the system at any time to reclaim
>   space.